# In Linear Algebra, does a vector equal its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, transpose

In this post: [why do people say “x dimensional vector"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152360/why-do-people-say-x-dimensional-vector-when-vectors-have-only-one-dimension) a question regarding vector dimension was framed. The response was more or less:

- vectors have dimension equal to space of which the vector is a member, in this case $\mathbb{R}^n$
- *rank* better describes what is being asked. Vectors have rank 1, Matrices rank 2, Tensors can be any rank.

Given that, if we assign
$$ \vec{b} = \vec{a}^T $$
does $$ \vec{b} == \vec{a} $$
or, more simply, does
$$ \vec{a} == \vec{a}^T $$

Comment: No they are not the same. If $x$ and $x^T$ are the same, you would be able to write $Ax^T$ instead of $Ax$.

Comment: Personally I would say no. Row vectors are really members of the dual space $V^*$ and should be thought of this way. There is a simple relationship between $a$ and $a^T$ however this strips away some of the structure on the vector space $V^*$.

Comment: I agree that these objects are not the same (unless $n=1$). That being said, mathematicians often blur the distinction between a vector and its transpose, trusting the context and the readers' understanding to stay away from pitfalls. Of course when the readers are just learning the subject, we shouldn't take this kind of short-cut.

Comment: @LinAlg, I had the same thought.. but then, where is the notion of 'orientation' being carried? Vectors have two attributes, rank and dimension? I guess Cameron Williams is saying its actually in the space vectors are drawn from?

Comment: @cameron, Thanks for the reply. So, in my example, $\mathbf{a}$ is a member of a space of column vectors and after transformation $\mathbf{b}$ is a member of a space of row vector of the same dimension. The 'attribute' I am looking for is the space.

Comment: @greg, Thanks for your reply. WRT blurring. I guess standard notation of vectors implies a vector in a space of column vectors. There is no notation to indicate a vector in a space of column vectors vs in a space of row vectors other than assuming column and using $a^T$ when you mean row. In my example above, were I to use $\mathbf{b}$ in $\mathbf{Ab}$, it would likely cause confusion as there is no indication it is in the space of row vectors.

Comment: thank you all for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. In order for an $m\times n$ matrix to equal an $m'\times n'$ matrix, you necessarily need $m=m'$ and $n=n'$. For example, the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$ is a $2\times 1$ matrix but its transpose, $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\end{bmatrix}$, is a $1\times 2$ matrix. Therefore, this vector does *not* equal its transpose.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I guess I'm stuck  the post I referenced above which described vectors has having a *Rank* of 1. With a rank of 1 can it have a 2-D index (m,n)? Still, if LinAlg is right, there must be Something that is being passed to C that indicates orientation. Vector attributes =(rank, dimension, orientation?)